# Pay fee for Tron contract method call with another account

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, tron, tronweb

I'm trying to transfer token (smart contract) from non activated account in Tron with tronweb to another account, the source account does not have any TRX.

Is it possible to pay fee for the transaction with another account?